# Make FAB respond to Soft Keyboard show/hide changes

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I've seen various posts about FABs responding to Snackbar popups at the bottom of the screen as well as scroll-sensitive FABs. But is there some implementation of `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` (or similar) **to move the FAB above the keyboard** when it pops up?

Right now, the keyboard covers the FAB when I click for example in an `EditText` box. My goal is to animate the FAB so it is always visible, independent of the keyboard status.

**EDIT:** Both `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `...="adjustPan"` won't change anything. Well, `adjustResize` resizes the underlying layout (which is in my case a map) but the FAB doesn't move.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216564/move-floating-action-button-above-keyboard

Comment: Came across it already. OP used a custom implementation of the FAB without `CoordinatorLayout`. Also changing `windowSoftInputMode` (as suggested in the answers) doesn't help as written in my EDIT.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, still waiting for answers

Answer (score 4):

Hi there i know it's old but for future or current readers/searchers and also the thread maker, he hasn't found answer yet. This is how i am having this behaviour in my app.

Fab hides on RecyclerView scroll, goes up when snack bar pops out, if fab is not shown and snackbar popus up and if you scroll then still Fab will be shown top of snack bar and will move down when SB disappears and last with keypad if it opens Fab will be pushed up. (sorry, i had to write coz i don't know how to give gif with eclipse emulator)

**Image**

[image]

**Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/GrayGood"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_appLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="com.faisal.cvcd.anim.ScrollingFABAnimation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
        android:tint="@color/White"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see i am using FabAnimation class to override some of its default methods.

**ScrollingFABAnimation**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ScrollingFABAnimation extends
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

public ScrollingFABAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

//For SnackBar to push up the Floating Button when it pops up
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent,    FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
    child.setTranslationY(translationY);
    return true;
}

//For FAB to hide or show on scroll
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target,
        int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL  || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child,
                    directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed,
        int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed,  dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

    if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        child.hide();
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        child.show();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an Android dev env set up so I can't test your solution, sorry. But thx for posting it!

Comment: This move upward Coordinator layout behavior is for SnackBar, not soft keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i tried to add a `ScrollView` inside my root view but it did not works because the content doesn't exceed the display's height (the fab react as expected in that case).

So i tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and it works for me.

For informations here's what my layout xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ManyViewsExceptScrollViews/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        [..]
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it's a `Fragment` inflated in an activity (in a `FrameLayout` that `match_parent` the root view) for which i added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest.