# FAB goes under keyboard after Snackbar is shown in android 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Normally when Snackbar is shown, Floating Action Button shifts up and then shifts down to its normal position when Snackbar hides. I have tested my application in all android versions before 6.0.1 and everything works as expected.

Unfortunately on android 6.0.1, after the Snackbar goes away the Floating Action Button goes half under the soft keyboard.

[image]

As per the Android guidelines I have `CoordinatorLayout` as the parent layout. And I have also tried: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is this some sort of bug? or is there any way to handle this programatically?

UPDATE: I have discovered that when I swipe to dismiss the Snackbar manually, the FAB comes back to its normal position. But if I let the snackbar until it hides/dismisses by itself, it will create the problem.

Using this approach suggested by `@Muhammad Faisal Hyder`: [Make FAB respond to Soft Keyboard show/hide changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746817/make-fab-respond-to-soft-keyboard-show-hide-changes/37785072#37785072) I am getting the following result:

[image]

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the XML code?

Comment: Sure I will post.

Answer (score 2):

I have given answer to this question asked by another person, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37785072/2736849) post, yes there is a programming way to handle it, we need to extend `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton>` and override methods to achieve appropriate behaviours of FAB on scrolling (to hide and show) and on snack bar or keyboard pops up so Fab also moves accordingly.

**After EDIT :**

Above referenced answer works for me, well you can try these as well.

add : `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in **`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout/>`**

If above doesn't work, still, then,

add : **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`** to your activity in `Manifest.xml`

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I will write my feedback as soon as I try your approach.

Comment: after adding ScrollingFABAnimation as my FAB layout_behavour I am getting a strange behavior. FAB goes up about half the size of the screen above the soft keyboard.

Comment: did you use same XML properties  ?

Comment: Same problem even after using your xml file.

Comment: FAB is located in the middle of the screen to the right. Something must be wrong with your code or some sort of compatibility issue with 6.0.1.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" are you sure about this ?
also add, android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in activity in manifest.xml.