# Set FAB (Floating Action Button) above keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, floating-action-button

Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216564/move-floating-action-button-above-keyboard) but without a proper answer.

I want the FAB to float on top of the keyboard. that's it.

For example

1. Open a new `Blank Activity` template project with Android Studio
2. Change the Hello World `TextView` to `EditText`
3. See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty easy,

- Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity in manifest
- Make sure your root view in layout xml, has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` property

Comment: It works without `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, at least for `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Or, programmatically: `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: It does NOT work combined with :         this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: It works without android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for ConstraintLayout as well.

Comment: Works without `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in coordinator layout as well

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see FloatingActionBar move above keyboard, you should:

**1)** **Insert FloatingActionBar inside CoordinatorLayout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_img" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**2) Add in root View (where your FAB exist) code:**

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true".
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AddFilm">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_img" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**3) Add next code in AndroidManifest.xml to your Activity:**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in particular fragment you can use this code and for activity just alter accordingly.

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            if (v.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top) > 500) {
                //Log.d("keyboardStatus","opened");
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
               // Log.d("keyboardStatus","closed");
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```